# Is there a way to have users that login their PC to have their authentication done using LDAP?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ldap, windows-authentication

I want to create an MVC application that takes the credentials the user uses to login to thier PC and use those credentials to verify if the user lies on a particular domain using LDAP and if he does then get his details from active directory.

Comment: what membership? @paparazzo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you to the user.

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsidentity(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

By using [System.DirectoryServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can get user related info from local LDAP.

```
var ldapPath = "your-domain-ldap-path"
var directoryEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath, UserName, Password, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);
```

Comment: When using the current windows user using "windowsIdentity" I get "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" not the username